# How to programmatically approve order using PayPal v2 orders API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like to use my sandbox mock customer credentials to programmatically approve 'order with intent to capture' I created earlier using the new v2 orders api.

My end goal is to have an end to end test where an order is created, approved, captured and refunded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PayPal method for programmatically approving an order. The two methods for approving an order are redirecting a user agent to the `approval_url` (legacy method), or using an [in-context Smart Button](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) (recommended).